# How to use @EnableCache , multiple CacheManagers and a custom cache resolver

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I am trying to have two Caffeine CacheManagers, one default and one named ("new.kid").
The named one is used for a particular method in a class NewKid and is designated by @Cacheable(cacheManager="new.kid") on the method (the annotation settings cannot be changed for the purpose of this problem).

I have defined a custom CacheResolver, overriden getCacheNames so that it returns the new.kid cache manager cache names for for targets of type NewKid and the defautl cache names otherwise.

There is actually not a lot of info on this, But from what I gathered, if one has more than one (the default) CacheManager, a custom CacheResolver is mandatory.
I have defined a custom CacheResolver, overriden getCacheNames so that it returns the new.kid cache manager cache names for for targets of type NewKid and the default cache manager names otherwise.
Full example (copied and modified form the Spring Caching Getting Started Guide) is available in my github https://github.com/tyonchev/spring-cache

```java
    @Component
    public class NewKid {
        @Cacheable(cacheManager="new.kid")
        public String whatsYourName(String input){
            return "New Kid Name " + input;
        }
    }
```

```java
    @Configuration
    public class NewKidCacheManager {
        @Bean("new.kid")
        public CacheManager newKidCacheManager() {
            CacheManager cmgr = new CaffeineCacheManager();
            ((CaffeineCacheManager) cmgr).setCacheNames(Arrays.asList(cacheName));
            ((CaffeineCacheManager) cmgr).setCaffeine(Caffeine.newBuilder());
            return cmgr;
        }
    }
```

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    public class CacheManagerConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value = "new.kid")
        CacheManager newKidCacheManager;

        @Bean
        @Override
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    ...
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Override
        public CacheResolver cacheResolver( ) {
            return new CustomResolver(newKidCacheManager);
        }
```

```java
class CustomResolver extends AbstractCacheResolver {

    public CustomResolver(CacheManager newKidCacheManager) {
        this.newKidCacheManager = newKidCacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getCacheNames(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> cacheOperationInvocationContext) {
        if (cacheOperationInvocationContext.getTarget() instanceof NewKid) {
            return newKidCacheManager.getCacheNames();
        } else {
            return getCacheManager().getCacheNames();
        }
    }
}
```

If I use @EnableCaching annotation I am stuck with a SimpleCacheResolver, that completely disregards my CustomResolver, albeit annotated with @Primary @Bean.
This causes this exception:

```
    No cache could be resolved for 'Builder[public java.lang.String hello.NewKid.whatsYourName(java.lang.String)] caches=[] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='new.kid' | cacheR
    esolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'' using resolver 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheResolver@171e2c13'. At least one cache should be provided per cache operation.
```

If I remove @EnableCaching, the correct CustomResolver is loaded, however, of course @Cacheable is completely disregarded, so method results are not cached

Am I doing something wrong, or one simply cannot use both EnableCaching and multiple CaceManagers with custom resolver ? How does it happen I am always stuck with SimpleCacheResolver even I have another CacheResolver bean marked as @Primary ? 
I would be happy if anyone could point me in the right direction

Comment: You have to specify the bean name of your custom `CacheResolver` that you wanna use e.g. `@Cacheable(cacheResolver="yourCustomResolverBeanName")`

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do this. This example illustrates my real-life problem, which is that I am using a library, exposing a bean with @Cacheable(cacheManager="..."). I have no control over this, and anyways, it is my understanding this should work.

Comment: It seems you're missing `value` attribute in `@Cacheable(cacheManager="new.kid")` annotation in the **NewKid** class. I don't think you need custom CacheResolver in your case, since you're already specifying the `cacheManager` attribute inside annotation. 
From `@Cacheable` docs _cacheManager_ attribute: _"Mutually exclusive with the {@link #cacheResolver}  attribute"_.  
So, try to remove custom cache resolver, and fix the annotation in the **NewKid** class e.g. some like: `@Cacheable(value = "newKidName", cacheManager="new.kid")`

Comment: ... and one more thing, mark one of the `CacheManager` beans as `@Primary`

Comment: @tyonchev were you able to resolve this? I am also looking for similar solution. But in my case, I have generic DAO class and looking for different cache name for each domain object query when used this generic DAO.